# Java JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, json, okhttp

I am trying to get JSON object from OpenSubtitles API. I don't know what is wrong with my code. I am using OkHttpClient and here is my code in below

**CODE**

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {                                                                                              
   @Override                                                                                                            
   public void run() {  
                                                                                            
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
       MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");                                                       
       RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n  \"file_id\": file_id\n}");                                
       Request request = new Request.Builder()                                                                          
               .url("https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download")                                                    
               .post(body)                                                                                              
               .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")                                                           
               .addHeader("Api-Key", "Api-Key")                                                
               .build();                                                                                                
                                                                                                                        
       try {      
                                                                                                  
           Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();                                                       
                                                                                                                        
           /// get date from your response                                                                              
           String responseBody = response.body().string();                                                              
                                                                                                                        
           ///// convert it to json object                                                                              
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);                                                        
                                                                                                                        
           Log.d("DATA: ", String.valueOf(jsonObject)); // this is where i get the error            
                                                                                                                        
           response.close();                                                                                            
                                                                                                                        
       } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                        
           e.printStackTrace();                                                                                         
           Log.d("IO EXCEPTION", "TIMEOUT");                                                                       
       } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                          
           e.printStackTrace();                                                                                         
           Log.d("OTHER EXCEPTION", "OTHER EXCEPTION");                                                                 
       }                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                    


  }).start();
```

**JSON OBJECT**

```
    {
  "link": "https://www.opensubtitles.com/download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subfile/Day.Shift.2022.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.Atmos.srt",
  "file_name": "Day.Shift.2022.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.Atmos.srt",
  "requests": 6,
  "remaining": 94,
  "message": "Your quota will be renewed in 21 hours and 44 minutes (2022-09-19 23:16:46 UTC) ",
  "reset_time": "21 hours and 44 minutes",
  "reset_time_utc": "2022-09-19T23:16:46.000Z"
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:165)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:182)
W/System.err:     at com.nomedia.restapi.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:104)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I tried adding my token to header but it still show the same error

Thanks for your input

Comment: The response body is empty and that is what you are getting that exception.  Your code should be checking the response code.

Comment: But what can make the response return an empty object ?

Comment: A failure response could.  Your code should be checking the response code.   BEFORE you attempt to parse the body.

Comment: thanks, i get the error code : Response{protocol=h2, code=406, message=, url=https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download}

Comment: Which most likely doesn't have an associated (non-empty) body.   406 means NOT ACCEPTABLE; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406.  Maybe you need to add "accept" headers? I suggest consulting the API documentation ...

Comment: Okay..., i checked thier forum : forum.opensubtitles.org and find out that there are many issues related to that even though i didn't find the solution yet.., but i contacted them, Thanks for your support.